Is it possible to catch ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE error in web application js files caused by browsers?
Sometimes the ERR_CACHE_READ_FAILURE occurs in my Chrome browser console when some resources are not correctly loaded from the browser cache, which can be reproduced on Window 10 Chromium kernal based browsers like Chrome or Edge by deleting the cache folder manually of the browsers, and the cache folders will be recovered if the page is reloaded. I would like to find a way to catch the error in js at runtime to reload the page.
I try to add an error handler in my js files but it doesn't work.
      window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
        if (event.message && event.message.toLowerCase().includes('err_cache_read_failure')) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });


Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question. See the formatting documentation for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

@Kaddath The cache object is deprecated according to this

My bad, should have looked before commenting

Can't repro on macOS. Is performance.getEntriesByType("resource") showing something different in such a case?

@Kaiido Neither do I. I guess it's because of the difference of implementation of Chrome on macOS and Windows.
